# Calling a function which manipulates the ostream doesn't require parentheses. C++

Tags: c++, function, operator-keyword, ostream, manipulators

I know a function cannot be called without a parentheses, however, let's say I have this piece of source code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

ostream& test(ostream& os){
os.setf(ios_base::floatfield);
return os;
}

int main(){
cout<<endl<<scientific<<111.123456789;
cout<<endl<<test<<111.123456789;
}

   /// Output:
   /// 1.11235e+002
   /// 111.123
```

There isn't any overloading for the left-shift operator, yet when I call the `test(ostream& os)` function in the `cout` at the `main` function, it does not require any parentheses. My question is why?

Comment: “There isn't any overloading for the left-shift operator” — yes there is.

Comment: The fact that you can call a function without parenthesis (i.e. that a function doesn't have to look like a function in the source code) is one of the *many* things I *hate* about C++.  Nevertheless, cout *does* "overload the shift left operator"- that's what you're looking at; that's how it works.  For example: [iostream.h](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/gcc/gcc-937.2/libio/iostream.h): `ostream& operator<<(char c);`.  PS: excluding the "h" header suffix is another thing I hate about C++ ;)

Comment: @paulsm4 Heathen! `.hpp` is for C++

Comment: @paulsm4: *"one of the many things I hate about C++"* - perhaps you're overlooking the utility (and beauty) of having templates (and even macros) handle different types using the same value-semantic notation used for e.g. `int`?... it's very elegant and powerful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> There isn't any overloading for the left-shift operator

Yes there is, it's defined in `<ostream>`.

It uses exactly the same technique that allows `endl` and `scientific` to work. There is an overload taking a function pointer, which calls the function pointer when it's written to a stream.

`basic_ostream` has these member functions which accept function pointers:

```
// 27.7.3.6 Formatted output:
basic_ostream<charT,traits>&
operator<<(basic_ostream<charT,traits>& (*pf)(basic_ostream<charT,traits>&))
{ return pf(*this); }

basic_ostream<charT,traits>&
operator<<(basic_ios<charT,traits>& (*pf)(basic_ios<charT,traits>&))
{ return pf(*this); }

basic_ostream<charT,traits>&
operator<<(ios_base& (*pf)(ios_base&))
{ return pf(*this); }
```

`cout << test` uses the first of those overloads, which is equivalent to `cout.operator<<(&test)`, which does `return test(*this);` so the call happens inside the overloaded `operator<<`.

Answer (score 6):

`ostream` has overload of [operator <<](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) for this case:

```
basic_ostream& operator<<(
    std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& (*func)(std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>&) );
```

> Calls func(*this);. These overloads are used to implement output I/O
>   manipulators such as std::endl.